# Best online kanji dictionary/software which shows the stroke order and names the strokes?

Tags: discussion, kanji

There are plenty of dictionaries that show the stroke order of kanji but don't go into detail on the kind of stroke.

Just to confirm what I mean by ''kind of stroke''. The kanji for mouth is 口. It is made of three strokes. 竖 横折 横 , vertical horizontal-turning horizontal.

It's obvious for the most part what the strokes are but sometimes it's not.

Please don't include links to Chinese character dictionaries and software. They do not cover the various differences that exist between Chinese characters and Japanese kanji. For example the character 箸. The kanji version has an extra 点 (dot stroke) hidden in there. If you are not sure what I mean by that then have a look at the following image. The 11th stroke is a 点 which doesn't exist in the Chinese character 箸.

[image]

The following is an example of a free online software that shows the order and names the strokes for Chinese characters. Please note the names of the strokes written below each stage. I am looking for something similar for kanji. Notice the image above does not list the stroke names.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'kind of stroke'? Are you referring to the 筆画?(https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AD%86%E7%94%BB). By the way, I don't understand what you mean when you say the kanji 箸 contains 点. Are you talking about ryakuji? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji

Comment: @kandyman I've added some info that answers your questions.

Comment: So you are searching for a resource which lists the category of each individual stroke in the kanji characters? All strokes in all characters, right?

Comment: @kandyman Yeah , I've added to my question to give an example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, that tool looks very useful indeed.

Comment: (Stroke type may refer to the stroke tips, and also to directionality of the stroke. Thank you.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a dictionary site which also lists the details for each individual stroke in every kanji, I don't know of an online tool which does that. There certainly may be some, so perhaps another user can help you with details.

Even so, I think you might find it useful to refer to Japanese calligraphy websites. There are some useful sites where you can input the kanji and see them written in a cursive style, mimicking brush strokes. While they may not explicitly state the type of stroke, if you are already familiar with writing kanji, then I think you will be able to distinguish the strokes. The site below is quite good, although I notice that it does not distinguish specifically between the two variants you mentioned: https://www.kenjisugimoto.com/shuji/index.html .
Here is what it looks like when you input a single kanji or compound words.
[image]

While this is not exactly what you are looking for, it might help when you are not sure about the strokes. It may be worth looking for other calligraphy resources as there might be more detailed sites which contain dictionaries of characters containing information on each stroke.

As for online dictionaries, I find [Kanshudo](https://www.kanshudo.com/dashboard) to be quite thorough in their treatment of kanji. It has many useful features in the free-to-use version and even more features in the paid version. It does distinguish the character you mention:

[image]

Hope that helps. I became interested in this difference between the variants of 箸 so I might post a question on the main Stack Exchange page!

Comment: Those are some nice resources. Thanks for those. I don't know if you speak Chinese or not but if you do and you have studied Chinese characters then you would know that these little variants are very common between Chinese characters and Japanese kanji. Anyway I'd really like a resource that just names the strokes in order like the second image I posted. It would remove any ambiguity.

Comment: I don't speak Chinese but although I am aware of kanji variants, I didn't realize that there were so many of them. I had thought that the differences were mainly between the Simplified Chinese characters and the current Japanese kanji which are older forms of Chinese which haven't change much.

Comment: I think "a resource which lists the category of each individual stroke in the kanji characters" does not exist in Japanese. I dabbled in Chinese a bit before and I was surprised how every stroke, not just the radicals, but every stroke has a name. It's amusing. Anyway, I find this site interesting in acquainting myself with semi cursive forms: http://www.yamasa.org/ocjs/kanjidic.nsf/SearchKanji3?OpenForm